# How do I fix this responsive background image for mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

The header image on [this site](http://seersuckermag.com/whitewashed/) was working fine until I added the code below on mobile so it would respect my media queries.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Now, if you load it on an iPhone, everything but the header is working as it should.

What code would I need to add to fix this?

CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url(images/5pointz_white_door.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;

}
```

[image: Incorrect Layout]

Comment: I don't see the problem from Chrome on iOS, what is it exactly?

Comment: @Zentaurus this is what i get. image is zoomed out but the right edge of the bold text is where it should cut off http://i.imgur.com/3ASuwdX.jpg